# VREP - Attaching Baxter manipulators

Tags: simulator

Trying to add manipulators to the VREP Baxter robot, I can add the gripper easily enough by adding the manipulator object in a scene to the appropriate arm tip and setting its position and rotation to 0 relative to parent.

However, the vacuum cup appears to require changes relative to parent of:

- position (+0.0015, +0.002, -0.055)
- rotation: -180 degrees in Alpha

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

1. why isn't the vacuum cup manipulator model defined to attach to the parent model by default (zero offsets)?
2. I arrived at the above values by trial and error; are they derivable from the model somehow?